# Insert ID Mapping into Map table

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-insert

Hi I have some patient IDs the I need to put into a table that will show what active ID the inactive ID will map to. I have two table like this:

MEMID       FirstName     Last Name
12                John                   Smith
24                Mike                   Perry
37                John                   Smith

ID     MEMID      IsActive
1         12                 1
2         24                 1
3         37                 0

I need to write a query to insert the data into a map table that will show the inactive John Smith ID maps to the active one. The table has this structure

ID     ActiveID       InactiveID
1            12                      37

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you identify 37 as the InactiveID for 12? Will there be only one InactiveID in the whole table (I doubt this is the case)?

Comment: There are more columns to the table like DOB that you can see the patients are duplicates so I have deactivated one instance of the name and want to map the active one to it. You see the IsActive column in the other table is 1 if the member is active.

Comment: This is simple `INNER JOIN`. Check this http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/02/different-types-of-joins/